# Button Gets Cut-Off in Grid Layout MAUI XAML

Tags: c#, android, xaml, button, maui

[Example of button cut-off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2qMB.png)

I have a situation where buttons I created within MAUI XAML gets cut-off and I am not sure how to rectify this. Unfortunately, my application I am trying to develop requires several buttons arranged within a certain pattern and therefore I need lots of grid rows and columns. How do I make button smaller to fit inside its "cell" within a grid.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Attached is an link of the result from the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test3.MainPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Text="One"
                TextColor="Black"
                
                FontSize="16"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                
                BorderColor="Black"
                BackgroundColor="Green"
                
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
        
        <Button Text="Two"
                TextColor="Black"
        
                FontSize="16"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
        
                BorderColor="Black"
                BackgroundColor="Orange"
        
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="9"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

        <Button Text="Three"
                TextColor="Black"

                FontSize="16"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                
                BorderColor="Black"
                BackgroundColor="Red"

                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="15"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

        <Button Text="1"
                TextColor="Black"
        
                FontSize="11"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
        
                BorderColor="Black"
                BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGrey"
        
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="2" 
                MaximumHeightRequest="10" />

        <Button Text="1"
                TextColor="Black"
                
                FontSize="11"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                
                BorderColor="Black"
                BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGrey"
                
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="2" 
                FontAutoScalingEnabled="True"/>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot yet embed images to my questions.

Comment: then post a link

Comment: A small comment. You could save a lot of lines if you use the more concise form of declaring RowDefinitions/ColumnDefinitions, e.g. `<Grid RowDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*" ... >`

Comment: @KillerQueen I am compelled to tell you to set horizontal and vertical options to fill. Then again, all this? For 5 buttons? Redesign it.

Comment: @StephenQuan Thanks, I am still learning and have seen this way of specifying a grid.

Comment: @H.A.H. I am still going to add other buttons. To be exact there will be 31 buttons horizontally and vertically positioned. This is just an example.

Comment: @Jason Okay, I have attached a link to the image.

Comment: @KillerQueen Can you comprehend the concept of minimal height? How can I explain it to you that <Grid RowDefinitions="*, 9999*"> cannot work. You are not giving even the minimal height for each button to be drawn. I told you, the answer for your question is set Vertical and Horizontal Options to Fill. But in this cell you cannot fit a button. You need to redesign it.

Answer (score 0):

I see that conceptually, you have a simple outer grid definition that looks like this:

|  | Horizontal Buttons |
| --- | --- |
| Vertical Buttons |  |

So, if you define 3 grids, one for the outer grid definition, another for your horizontal buttons, another for your vertical buttons, your XAML would be greatly simplified, e.g.

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *"
      ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *">
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*,*" Grid.Column="1">
        <Button Text="One"/>
        <Button Text="Two" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Button Text="Three" Grid.Column="4"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*,*" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Text="Four"/>
        <Button Text="Five" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button Text="Six" Grid.Row="4"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: grid-preview]